# How can I get jQuery ajax result data in IE7 or IE8?

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

in my Controller, my code is like this,

```
int resultCount = 3;
mav.addObject("resultCount", resultCount);
```

---

and my jsp code is like this,

```
$.ajax({
     url: ....,
     type: 'POST',
     data: ....,
     success: function( result ) {
         if(result.resultCount != null){
               *// here, I can see resultCount(3)  in Chrome or IE9 
               // but it's undefiend in IE7 or IE8*
         }
     },
     error : function(error){
     }
```

My question is how I get the resultCount in IE7 or IE8.

When I console or alert the result, it contains resultCount ("resultCount":3).

I might ask a stupid question, but please give me any idea.
thanks.

Comment: It's not a stupid question. We just need additional information. What `dataType` is your request coming back as (i.e. xml, string, json...etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding `dataType:'json'`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ....,
    type: 'POST',
    data: ....,
    dataType: 'json',
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.resultCount != null) {
            * // here, I can see resultCount(3)  in Chrome or IE9 
            // but it's undefiend in IE7 or IE8*
        }
    },
    error: function (error) {
    }
```

Comment: The OP would also have to modify the return headers on the server to get this to work. Even if the results are correct, if the client asks for `json` and does not receive it, jQuery will usually fall into the error callback.

Comment: @War10ck, well...without seeing the full server code, we'll never be sure...  but it seems to be related to the `dataType`.

Comment: Oh I agree with you. Without seeing additional code I think we've said all we can say. It should just be noted though that the OP might have to slightly modify the response headers for this to work correctly. Just a side note. :)